# Create a SQL dump with join tables

Tags: mysql

I have to transfer the following select into a single table:

```
SELECT  
o.objektnummer, su.subunternehmernummer,
a.artikelnummer, a.artikel, a.beschreibung,
a.einheit, a.preis_pro_einheit, a.anzahl_parameter, a.p1_einheit, a.p2_einheit, a.p3_einheit,
a.mbs_artikel, a.su_gewerk, a.preis_status,
a.mindermenge_kleiner_als, a.zulage_mindermengen_artikel_nummer
FROM
objekt_artikel oa
INNER JOIN objekt o ON o.id = oa.id_objekt
INNER JOIN artikel a ON a.id = oa.id_artikel
INNER JOIN subunternehmer_objekt suo ON suo.id_objekt = o.id
INNER JOIN subunternehmer su ON su.id = suo.id_subunternehmer
```

This is the insert i nead:

```
INSERT INTO objekt_artikel (
                    id_objekt, id_subunternehmer,
                    artikelnummer, artikel, beschreibung,
                    einheit, preis_pro_einheit, anzahl_parameter, p1_einheit, p2_einheit, p3_einheit,
                    mbs_artikel, su_gewerk, preis_status,
                    mindermenge_kleiner_als, zulage_mindermengen_artikel_nummer
                     )
```

If i set Limit to 1000, then the select works perfect and the insert could be done, but the table  from the select have over 19 000 000 rows and this makes the server crashing. My idea is now, that i make a sql-dump with this select, but i think the problem is that i have so much inner joins in it.

Can i make a output with this select to a file? seperatet by semikolon?

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with 19 million rows! But I can think of one solution that can be implemented by whoever is calling these SQL statements. I give the pseudo-code below:

```
for ($start=0, $limit=1000; ; $start += $limit) {
    $result = execute("SELECT * FROM $tableName LIMIT $start, $limit");
    if ($result) insertToTable($result);
    else break;
}
```